# Inserting multiple rows in sybase with a single sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I am trying to insert multiple rows in sybase.

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway'),
       ('Cardinal2','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway'),
       ('Cardinal3','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway');
```

I am only getting the first record inserted.

Comment: Do you have a unique constraint on a column?Use different values for all columns.

Comment: @user2092096 Did you run AmirAbbas Sherafatian's query with out insert ?